# My computer ran CHKDSK before startup

Tags: windows-7, windows, sony-vaio, chkdsk

This happened on an old "SONY VAIO" Model: PCG-61112L. This computer was broken and I have fixed it but when I turned it on winload.exe was missing so then I created a windows 7 repair drive and fixed it up. Now I have windows 7 on my computer and when I started it up I was excited. But then the computer ran CHKDSK on startup and I thought I did something wrong. I'm wondering if this is normal after repairing/reinstalling windows.

Comment: What was the result of CHKDSK? Any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2854570/check-disk-chkdsk-runs-when-you-start-windows-8-or-windows-7 Windows 7 will run chkdsk on startup when:

> Cause 1
>   You removed a storage device from the computer after hibernation, changed the data on the device, reattached the device, and then resumed the computer. 
>   When a Windows-based computer enters hibernation, all the necessary information such as system state and memory content to a file (Hiberfile) is stored. When the computer is resumed, Windows reads the Hiberfile to re-create the environment that is exactly same as before the computer was hibernated. Because the contents of the storage device have changed after the computer enters hibernation, the information that computer had about the volumes on the storage device is incorrect. Therefore data corruption or inconsistencies occur after you resume the computer.

This could have happened in your case. When the computer was last used it was put into hibernation and the repair caused files to be changed.

However

> Cause 3
>   Windows has detected NTFS file system errors. Your computer's hard disk has file system errors. Therefore, you must run a scan to fix the errors on the drive.

can also be very likely since the computer is very old and hard disk will start to fail at some point.

If you have any important data on that computer I would highly recommend to make a backup of any documents, pictures etc., even if the drive is not failing it still very old and especially if used a lot may already have some bad sectors.
You can check the S.M.A.R.T values of the disk via a  software called [CrystalDiskInfo](https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskinfo/) which also displays the drives health depending on how many sectors failed etc.

Comment: Yes, thank you. But my problem isn't chkdsk that confused me my problem is that I have no way of turning the computer on and running windows. because winload.exe in missing. therefore i cannot check what wrong with the hard drive
the hard drive is a Sony VAIO PCG-6112L 500GB SATA 5400RPM 2.5in 7mm

Comment: If you have another computer with a free SATA port and power you can plug the drive into that one and check the status via CrystalDisk on that one (and copy important files). If not you can create a bootable USB / CD with some live Linux system like Xubuntu. (https://xubuntu.org/) After booting from that you will be able to copy your important files, after that simply reinstall Windows.